# SQL Server AD authentification just from specific client

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2017

Is there a way to limit the access to a SQL Server 2017 for an AD user or group connected with a specific client?

For example to permit only connections or queries from a client who has the IP of `192.168.2.5`.

Comment: You could limit connections over port 1433 to the whitelisted IP address(es) in Windows Firewall.

Comment: Unfortunately thats not possible 'cause there are many many users who need access to the server by any ip. I need to limit the access just for a specific user.

Comment: Oh! Then a logon trigger should work. Here's a duplicate question on dba.stackexchange.com: [link](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/84204/sql-server-how-to-create-user-with-access-only-from-specific-hostname-or-ip-ad)

Comment: Great, thanks! I'll give that a try